# Connect VSCode to existing Scratch Org

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, visualstudiocode

I have two scratch orgs and one non scratch org. I restarted my Visual Studio Code and lost my connection to the scratch org.
Can someone please tell me how to connect VS code to existing scratch orgs.

```
Scratch orgs
=============================================================================
|   ALIAS    USERNAME                      ORG ID             EXPIRATION DATE 
| ─ ──────── ───────────────────────────── ────────────────── ─────────────── 
|   sixthlms test-sdk7uiawqlqu@example.com 00D1y0000003WYhEAM 2023-09-01      
|   ThirdLms test-029tsmeit5wr@example.com 00D0p0000002PG3EAM 2023-09-01
```

Thanks in Advance,
Nikhila

Comment: Thank you, it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code uses the standard settings for a project folder. You can use the menu item in VS Code to set the default user name (click on the "plug" icon in the lower-left corner), or use `sf config set target-org=username-or-alias`).